# Access barometer sensor with flutter

Tags: air, flutter, pressure

I didn't find a way to access the barometer(sensor for air pressure) of my smartphone with flutter. I only want to use it with android, because iPhones doesn't have a barometer. Is there an known way to do that or do i have to make a native android app with Kotlin or Java.

Comment: I don't think there is a plugin available for that yet. You'd need to build your own like https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sensors, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/proximity_plugin. https://flutter.io/developing-packages/

Comment: Recent iPhones definitely have a barometer.

Comment: Did you find one ?